# Page does not refresh automatically after DELETE and UPDATE item on the lists. React-Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am having this problem where my page does not refresh automatically after deleting Item on the list. The item in the list is deleted but I need to manually refresh the page to see the updated list. Is there any way to improve the code?

This is the List.js Action.
**Action**

```
//Update user action

export const UPDATE_USER = 'UPDATE_USER';
export const updateUser = (id, ...data) => async (dispatch, getState, api) => {
const res = await api.put('/user/update/' + id, data[0])
    .then(function (res) {
        return res;
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        return err.response;
    });

dispatch({
    type: UPDATE_USER,
    payload: res.data
});
};

// Delete user actions
export const DELETE_USER = 'DELETE_USER';
export const deleteUser = (id) => async (dispatch, getState, api) => {
const res = await api.delete('/user/del/' + id, null)
    .then(function (res) {
        return res;
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        return err.response;
    });

dispatch({
    type: DELETE_USER,
    payload: res.data,
    state: getState
});
};
```

This is the UserList.js Component.
**Components**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import moment from 'moment';
import {deleteUser} from '../Actions/Update';
import {handleModal} from "../Actions/Global";

class UsersList extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}

editUser(user) {
    this.props.handleModal(user);
}

handleDelete(userid) {
    this.props.deleteUser(userid);
}

renderUsers(users) {
    return users.map((user) => {
        return (
            <tr key={user.id}>
                <td>{user.firstName}</td>
                <td>{user.lastName}</td>
                <td>{this.displayCurrentOrg(user)}</td>
                <td className="md-visible"> . 
{moment(user.createdAt).format('MM.DD.YYYY')}</td>
                <td>
                    <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={() => 
this.editUser(user)}><i
                        className="fa fa-edit"></i></button>
                    <button
                        className="btn btn-danger"
                        onClick={() => {
                            if (window.confirm('Are you sure to delete this 
user?')) this.handleDelete(user.id)
                        }}><i className="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        );
    })
}
render() {
    return (
        <table className="table table-responsive-lg">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Current Organization</th>
                <th className="md-visible">Registered</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            {this.renderUsers(this.props.users)}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    )
  }
 }

 function mapStateToProps(globalState) {
 return {};
 }

 export default connect(mapStateToProps, {deleteUser, handleModal}) . 
 (UsersList);
```

This is the UserUpdates Reducers.
**Reducers**

```
import {ADD_USER} from '../Actions/Create';
import {DELETE_USER, UPDATE_USER} from '../Actions/Update';

export default (state = null, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_USER:
        return action.payload;
    case DELETE_USER:
        return action.payload;
    case UPDATE_USER:
        return action.payload;
    default:
        return state;
   }
   };
```

Comment: What data is returned by api?

Comment: {"success":true,"message":"Removed successfully"} @JiteshManglani

Comment: Initial state is a user list, after dispatch DELETE_USER, next state should be new user list without the deleted one. But your reduce makes new state equal to { success: true, message: 'xxx' }

Comment: @喝茶的螃蟹 if that I think the list users will be empty. Because the new `state` have no `users` property, but `success` and `message` only?

Comment: Can you show us the `console.log(res)` right before `dispath` line in `delete` function?

Comment: The list is not update after I delete or update unless i refresh the page.

Comment: @Tam Dc Yes, `users` will be empty and `users.map` will report an error of `Can not read property 'map' of undefined `. 
Something is unclear:
   1. how the `users` property connect to `UserList`
   2. what's the new value of `users` in store is after dispatch action `DELETE_USER `

Comment: The users list is gotten as a props in Users.js from a Redux Reducer Users.js (who is defined with an axios request to the api.It's then sent as a props to UsersList.js

Comment: @喝茶的螃蟹 but OP has the same data. Maybe the error message is shown in the dev tool console. And then did not change the UI.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `payload` data you use to `dispatch` has the wrong format. I assume your `state` here is the `users` list. Then I think the code should be:

```
export const deleteUser = (id) => async (dispatch, getState, api) => {
  const res = await api.delete('/user/del/' + id, null)
    .then(function (res) {
      if(res.success) {
        dispatch({
          type: DELETE_USER,
          payload: { id },
          state: getState
        });
      }
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      return err.response;
    });
};

// Reducer
case DELETE_USER: {
      const newList = state.filter(e => e.id !== action.payload.id)
      return newList ;
    }
```

Comment: The Item in the list is deleted but still the lists are not updated until I refresh the page.

Comment: The problem here is the new `users` list use to update the store after deleted was not right. And can you tell me what in the `state`? like: `state = { users: [], ...}` or `state = users`

Answer (score 0):

You should dispatch action of reloading data after you receive success of delete or update. That should update your list and UI. By this you don't need to refresh page to see data changes.

I am having this problem where my page does not refresh automatically after deleting Item on the list. The item in the list is deleted but I need to manually refresh the page to see the updated list. Is there any way to improve the code?

This is the List.js Action. Action

```
//Update user action

export const UPDATE_USER = 'UPDATE_USER';
export const updateUser = (id, ...data) => async (dispatch, getState, api) => {
const res = await api.put('/user/update/' + id, data[0])
    .then(function (res) {
        return res;
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        return err.response;
    });

dispatch({
    type: UPDATE_USER,
    payload: res.data
});
dispatch({
   type: LOAD_USER
});
};

// Delete user actions
export const DELETE_USER = 'DELETE_USER';
export const deleteUser = (id) => async (dispatch, getState, api) => {
const res = await api.delete('/user/del/' + id, null)
    .then(function (res) {
        return res;
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        return err.response;
    });

dispatch({
    type: DELETE_USER,
    payload: res.data,
    state: getState
});
dispatch({
   type: LOAD_USER
});
};
```

I have dispatch LOAD_USER action for that may be you are referring to other action which load your users data for display.

Comment: what does the reducer should look like?

Comment: How are you loading data first time that action can be dispatched here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some abstract of what you should do in order to see the updated user list:

```
// Update user list action
export const UPDATE_USER_LIST = 'UPDATE_USER_LIST';
export const updateUsers = () => async (dispatch, api) => {
    const res = await api
        .put('/users') // you need to use GET on the URI where you store the users 
        .then(res => {
            return res;
        })
        .catch(err => {
            return err.response;
        });

    dispatch({
        type: UPDATE_USER_LIST,
        payload: res.data
    });
};

// Delete user action
export const DELETE_USER = 'DELETE_USER';
export const deleteUser = (id) => async (dispatch, getState, api) => {
const res = await api.delete('/user/del/' + id, null)
    .then(function (res) {
        // you should call another action to update the User list
        dispatch({
            type: UPDATE_USER_LIST
        });
        return res;
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        return err.response;
    });

    dispatch({
        type: DELETE_USER,
        payload: res.data,
        state: getState
    });
};

// The reducer
import {ADD_USER} from '../Actions/Create';
import {DELETE_USER, UPDATE_USER} from '../Actions/Update';

export default (state = null, action) => {

    switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_USER:
            return action.payload;
        case DELETE_USER:
            return action.payload;
        case UPDATE_USER:
            return action.payload;
            // add a case where you get the payload and place it in the users state in the store
        case UPDATE_USER_LIST:
            return action.payload
        default:
            return state;
       }

   };
```

You should query your users URI (GET) and use pass the payload into your reducer to get the new version of your user list.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: can you explain what should I get in payload apart from status code 200